# Query The Table Using PHP Substr() Function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a case to query the table using **WHERE** clause in which I just want to use a 'piece of string' from the field to compare to my string as a condition for selecting.

In the picture, I just want to use **month** and **year** from **date** field to compare with `$indicator = 03/2013`.

Any idea how can performing the query, so the result would look like:

[image]

Any help will appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you aren't dealing with strings in the table, as it's most likely dates.  If you are dealing with strings, it's

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE LIKE '%03/2013';
```

where % is a wildcard like * in the old dos days

For actual date fields, (which you would be better off using), it's a simple between

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '01/03/2013' AND '31/03/2013'
```

Note that you need to follow proper date formatting for your engine, for something like MySQL you'd be better off using `'2013-03-01'` and `'2013-03-31'`

The hardest part will be coming up with the first and last day, but for that, I'd look at [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), which allows you to put in things like `'Last day of the month'` and such.  You'd have to format it correctly, and play with the strings, but it's rather trivial with what strtotime() can do.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

USE `LIKE` in your mysql query instead of `=`

Reference : ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html))

Comment: Please note, just switching to LIKE doesn't fix anything, as LIKE is even more strict of a comparison then = is.  You need to use %'s to set up wildcard patterns in the comparison.

Comment: @AndrewLeap your right but better checking the resource link first would be great for you..

Comment: Don't know what you mean by that, I did check that reference link, specifically `Per the SQL standard, LIKE performs matching on a per-character basis, thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator:`

Comment: @AndrewLeap didnt you read it first buddy :D. wildcards always an option for using `LIKE`.my point is the source link clearly explained how to use `LIKE` in any aspect providing different results so why would i needed to explain it again.Sometimes need to pay attention reading it..

Comment: Well, sorry, but I tend to actually explain stuff when I'm answering questions.  That may not be the norm, but that's how I roll.  Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question